# Need Help using hook_views_query_filter

Tags: 6, views

I am using hook_views_query_filter to append my own where clause condition with the where clause of the query generated by the view.

So for this I am using this hook.

Here is my code

```
   function mymodule_views_query_filter(&$view, $query) {
 if($view->name = "myview") {
 $query->where[1] = array(
            'clauses' => array(
                            '0'=>"field_test_value=0",

                             ),
            'args' => array('0' => 'test1', '1' => 'test2'),
            'type' => 'OR',
            );
}
print_r($query);
}
```

So the where clause becomes like this after print_r() funtion.

```
[where] =&gt; Array
    (
        [0] =&gt; Array
            (
                [clauses] =&gt; Array
                    (
                        [0] =&gt; node.type in ('%s')
                        [1] =&gt; node.status &lt;&gt; 0
                        [2] =&gt; term_data.name = '%s'
                        [3] =&gt; term_data_term_node__term_data.name = '%s'
                    )

                [args] =&gt; Array
                    (
                        [0] =&gt; test1
                        [1] =&gt; test2l
                        [2] =&gt; test3
                    )

                [type] =&gt; AND
            )

        [1] =&gt; Array
            (
                [clauses] =&gt; Array
                    (
                        [0] =&gt; field_test_value=0
                    )

                [args] =&gt; Array
                    (
                        [0] =&gt; test1
                        [1] =&gt; test2
                    )

                [type] =&gt; OR
            )

    )
```

Where the 0 index of the where clause is coming from the view query and the 1 index of the where is clause is coming from my code.
But it only executes the 1 index of the where clause and display the results only if Where field_test_value=1 and I want something like this.

```
Where (node.type in ('%s') AND node.status <> 0 AND term_data.name = '%s' AND term_data_term_node__term_data.name = '%s') OR field_test_value=0
```

Comment: anyone who have idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't alter the query objects properties directly. You need to use the methods it provides. In this case, you need to use `add_where()`. I think you want to consider something like this:

```
<?php
$clauses = array("field_test_value='%s'");
$args = array('test1');
$query->add_where(1, $clauses, $args);
$query->set_group_operator('OR'); // this is the operator that goes between WHERE groups
?>
```